# firestore - retrieve data by filtering arrayField

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am storing data in firestore in the format

```
feed: { userID, title, description, ..., hideFor[userID] }
```

I want to query feeds such that loggedin user should not see the feed if his/her id is listed in `hideFor[]` array. Which firestore query method/operator can help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `in` operator
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any

If you use angular/fire then it would be something along like

```
this.afs.collection('feed', q=> { return  q.where( userId, 'in','hideFor'})
```

edit: realized you wanted not in then the operator is `not-in` but same pattern

Comment: I forgot to mention... your proposed solution I already tried this filter but no luck. The error is thrown as 
    "core.mjs:6484 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Invalid Query. A non-empty array is required for 'not-in' filters.
FirebaseError: Invalid Query. A non-empty array is required for 'not-in' filters."

As per firestore documentation the correct usage of not-in operator is 
where(fieldName, 'not-in', ['val1', 'val2', 'val3']